# Something wrong in my cogs about on_message_edit

Tags: discord.py

So, I want to log the edited message by member if they change it
This is my code in the cogs so far:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_edit(self,message,before,after):
        guild = message.guild
        channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name="║logs")
        embed = discord.Embed(timestamp=message.created_at, colour=red) 
        embed.set_author(name=f'{message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}', icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Author ID:{message.author.id} • Message ID: {message.id}")
        embed.add_field(name="Member", value=f"<@{message.author.id}>", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Channel", value=f"<#{message.channel.id}>", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Message content before edited", value=message.before.content, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Message content after edited", value=message.after.content, inline=False)
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

When I test it, I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message_edit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message_edit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'after'
```

I don't get it. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there is no `message` argument in `on_message_edit` event. Just do this:

```py
async def on_message_edit(self,before,after):
```

The `before` is `discord.Message` object before edit and the `after` is `discord.Message` object after edit.

Comment: but if I do that, the ``guild=message.guild`` will become invalid

Comment: Yes so replce it with either `guild=before.guild` or `guild=after.guild`, this two will always be the same.